# How can I create a complex table like this in the following picture

Tags: tables

I want to create a table like this in latex
[image: table picture]

How could I do that? I can create simple tables, but this one is far too difficult for me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although you can't complete the table yet, but please post here what you have tried -- that will help us a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will post it later!

Comment: You might be interested in using the `\multicolumn` command and the `enumitem` package for a customized list that fit into a table cell. `tabularx` might also be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is another alternative where I have centered a signature at in the lower right corner that seems more coherent.

Here there is a screenshot of the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|llllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{xxx} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{xxx} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}|}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{major} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{11cm}|}{
Comments
\begin{enumerate}
        \item Some text
        \item Some text
        \item Some text
        \item Some text
    \end{enumerate} Signature: \rule{8cm}{1pt} } \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|ll|l|}
\hline
Name           &            & xxx & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & xxx         &         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{major} & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{comments}                                                    \\
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{1. Some text}                                                \\
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{2. Some text}                                                \\
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{3. Some text}                                                \\
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Signature:}                                                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! I will try to do the adjustment myself.